# Write OSX Kernel extension with SWIFT?

Tags: macos, swift, kernel-extension

I need to create an kernel extension for OSX in order to write a low level keyboard driver for a custom keyboard.

Since I don't know Objective-C nor Swift I have to pick one language to learn. I'd prefer Swift but don't know if it's possible to write kernel extensions with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No not at this point. Kernel Extensions are written in C or a subset of C++.